# How are multiple symbols displayed as one called and what is the purpose of them?

Tags: html, validation, fonts, special-characters

How do you call characters like this annoying one below? What are they supposed to do, or more importantly - why do they even exist? :) Can I somehow add them to my HTML source (and is it valid) and eventually don't let the users put them into comments etc.?

```
̷̲̙̲͇̲̙̲̹̲̙̲͇̲̙̲̲̙̲͇̲̙̲͇̲̙̲͇̲̙̲᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅a̲̙̲͇̲̙̲͈̲̙̲͇̲̙̲̪̲̙̲͇̲̙̲̲̙̲͇̲̙̲᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷉᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/10q44c74/

Comment: I'm afraid it might be really tricky to block them, as even stackoverflow can't do that: ̷̲̙̲͇̲̙̲̹̲̙̲͇̲̙̲̲̙̲͇̲̙̲͇̲̙̲͇̲̙̲᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅a̲̙̲͇̲̙̲͈̲̙̲͇̲̙̲̪̲̙̲͇̲̙̲̲̙̲͇̲̙̲᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷉᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅᷅ :( < sorry for that guys, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: "annoying" is subjective and pretty much irrelevant when asking questions. Even if you think it's annoying, the text itself is just inert text, devoid of emotion or intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're simply a sequence of unicode [combining diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). In this case about 118 meaningless ones in a row.

What is their purpose? The wikipedia article explains it just fine, but let's combine the letter `n` and the combining tilde diacritic. Hurray, now we can write out añejo (as a *six* unicode codepoints string, that is rendered as five *letters*).

Of course, you can be silly and just combine a hundred combining marks to produce nonsense. Usually there's no point in restricting this: even if it looks like one letter, it's still 118 code points, and anything with a character limit will count each diacritic as one fewer real letters you can type.

It's also good for writing awesome crazy stuff,  [l̙̣͇ͦ̈́ͫ͌ͤ͊̿i̻̱͍̽͐̂̑ͪk̹̞̼̫͔ẻ̫̯ ̦͔͎̿t̼̼͔̰̿͋̈́ͬͨhͯ͛̚i̖ͤs͙͓̻̝̗̼̈́͂ ̠̮͉̙̲̺̿ͅk͖ͤ͆̒̅̾́̉ì̪͎̗͓̻̪ͤn͍̥̱̠̲̳̖̓ͤ̿d̟̮̍̾ͩ̂ ̜͖͉̠o͚̠̾ͥ͌̔f̭̖ͥͤͦ̉ͨ ̦̌t̳̩͐͐ͤẹ̉̃x̟̙̌ͥͯ̈͂̆͌t.](http://www.marlborotech.com/Zalgo.html)